# How to send login request in python?

Tags: python, html, http-request

i am trying this python script:

```
import httplib
import urllib

conn = httplib.HTTPConnection("moodle.tau.ac.il")
conn.request("POST" , "/hu11/?lang=en_utf8&username=bugs&password=bunny" )
response = conn.getresponse()
print response.status, response.reason
print response.read()
conn.close()
```

but it doesn't log in the site as i want to. i want to build some script to help a friend to download all the files from his courses.

what do i do wrong in setting a post request to the server?

i have this form tag in site i would like to login to with python script:

```
 <form action="" method="post" id="login">
          <div class="loginform">
            <div class="form-label"><label for="username">Username</label></div>
            <div class="form-input">
                            <input type="text" name="username" id="username" size="8" maxlength=8 value="" />
                          </div>
            <div class="clearer"><!-- --></div>
            <div class="form-label"><label for="password">Password</label></div>
            <div class="form-input">
                            <input type="password" name="password" id="password" size="5" value="" />
                            <br /><br />
              <input type="submit" value="Login" />
              <input type="hidden" name="testcookies" value="0" />
                          </div>
            <div class="clearer"><!-- --></div>
          </div>
        </form>
```

Comment: Are you getting an error message? If so, what is it? Also, is there any particular reason you're using `httplib.HTTPConnection` rather than the higher-level `urllib2.urlopen`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) or [Mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/).